# Getting a dendrogram's branch lengths in a breadth-first-search order

Tags: r, breadth-first-search, dendrogram

Is there any `R` function to retrieve the branch lengths of a dendrogram:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100*10),nrow=100,ncol=10)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(mat))))
```

in a breadth-first-search order?

For `dend` I'd like to get this result:

```
c(16.38688,15.41441,15.99504,14.68365,13.52949,14.39275,12.96921,13.91157,13.15395)
```

which is node depths (excluding leaves) ordered by bps.

Thanks

Comment: A function in the `plotrix` package called `listDepth` looks like it could work.  The title is "Find the maximum depth of a list."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100*10),nrow=100,ncol=10)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(mat))))
```

Using the `data.tree` package allows traversing trees in various orders. `level` will give what the question specifies:

```
require(data.tree)
dend.dt <- as.Node(dend)
sapply(Traverse(dend.dt,traversal = "level", pruneFun = isNotLeaf),function(x) x$plotHeight)
[1] 16.38688 15.41441 15.99504 14.68365 13.52949 14.39275 12.96921 13.91157 13.15395
```

Comment: It's better to include some context/explanation with code as this makes the answer more useful for the OP and for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily code one like this:

```
dendro_depth <- function(dendro){
  if(!is.null(attributes(dendro)$leaf))
    0
  else
    max(dendro_depth(dendro[[1]]),dendro_depth(dendro[[2]])) +1
}
```

Comment: Can you get this to return a bfs sorted vector of node heights?

Answer (score 1):

See `get_branches_heights` from [dendextend](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/index.html).

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(rnorm(100*10),nrow=100,ncol=10)
dend <- as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(t(mat))))

library(dendextend)
get_branches_heights(dend, sort = F)
```

It does not seem to be exactly in the order youu want, but see if this is still useful:

```
> get_branches_heights(dend, sort = F)
[1] 16.38688 15.41441 14.68365 15.99504 13.52949
[6] 12.96921 14.39275 13.91157 13.15395
```

BTW, the recent github version of dendextend also comes with the `highlight_branches` function for coloring branches based on branch height (in case this is somehow related to your motivation):

```
plot(highlight_branches(dend))
```

[image]